# How to find out which kernel module opened a socket?

Tags: linux, kernel, socket, wireguard, kernel-modules

When I try to find the process for an opened socket using e.g. ss I get the following output:

```
❯ sudo ss -tulpen
Failed to open cgroup2 by ID
Failed to open cgroup2 by ID
Netid State  Recv-Q Send-Q         Local Address:Port   Peer Address:Port Process
udp   UNCONN 0      0                    0.0.0.0:33333       0.0.0.0:*     ino:14386 sk:1 cgroup:unreachable:9e4 <->
udp   UNCONN 0      0                       [::]:33333          [::]:*     ino:14387 sk:2 cgroup:unreachable:9e4 v6only:1 <->
tcp   LISTEN 0      50                 10.20.0.1:445         0.0.0.0:*     users:(("smbd",pid=336,fd=48)) ino:14500 sk:3 cgroup:/system.slice/smb.service <->
tcp   LISTEN 0      50                 10.20.0.1:139         0.0.0.0:*     users:(("smbd",pid=336,fd=49)) ino:14501 sk:8 cgroup:/system.slice/smb.service <->
tcp   LISTEN 0      4096                 0.0.0.0:80          0.0.0.0:*     users:(("docker-proxy",pid=25926,fd=4)) ino:108903 sk:1085 cgroup:/system.slice/docker.service <->
tcp   LISTEN 0      50                   0.0.0.0:443         0.0.0.0:*     users:(("sslh-select",pid=24592,fd=3)) uid:63671 ino:102824 sk:1001 cgroup:/system.slice/sslh-select.service <->
tcp   LISTEN 0      4096                    [::]:80             [::]:*     users:(("docker-proxy",pid=25938,fd=4)) ino:108912 sk:108d cgroup:/system.slice/docker.service v6only:1 <->
tcp   LISTEN 0      50                      [::]:443            [::]:*     users:(("sslh-select",pid=24592,fd=4)) uid:63671 ino:102825 sk:107e cgroup:/system.slice/sslh-select.service v6only:1 <->
```

I know I setup wireguard using the kernel module at UDP:33333 but I tend to forget stuff like that after some time. Is there a way to reliably determine the module responsible for a 'kernel' socket?